# Nested states won't load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I've tried making nested states, with no luck so far.

What I've got so far is this

**search.route.js**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/search', '/search/model');

    $stateProvider
        .state('search', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/search'
        });
});
```

**model.route.js**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('search.model', {
            url: '/model',
            templateUrl: 'app/search/model/model.html',
            controller: 'modelController'
        });
});
```

if I use `searchModel` as state name and `/search/model` as url rather than `search.model` and `/model` it works fine.

**EDIT**
Okay, I wasn't clear the first time around ^^

Originally my code looked like this:

**model.route.js**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('searchModel', {
            url: '/search/model',
            templateUrl: 'app/search/model/model.html',
            controller: 'modelController'
        });
});
```

this worked fine. When I went to the url `/search/model` the html file along with the controller would load in.

But then I changed it to the code visible in the beginning of my question. Now when navigating to the url it won't load in the html along with the controller. I recieve no error messages or similar things which might give me a clue as to why it won't load in.

Comment: please clear it by elaborating more\

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `<ui-view>` in abstract state for child states to load into.

Try:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('search', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/search'. 
        template: '<ui-view></ui-view>'
    });
```

See [Nested States docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views)